# Why does RNA adopt an A-form helix?

Tags: biochemistry, rna, structural-biology

RNA is known to form an A-form helix, while DNA generally forms a B-form helix under physiological conditions.

[image]

<sub>From left to right: A-form DNA, B-form DNA, Z-form DNA. Image created by [Richard Wheeler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/user:Zephyris)</sub>

The preference of RNA for the different conformation is supposed to be caused by the 2'-OH, my question is now how exactly this favors the A-helix? Which interactions are important and cause RNA to adopt an A-form helix?

Comment: There are many factors that produce effect in that interaction. You could have a first look in detail at http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022283605014439

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The beta-form of DNA and the alpha-form of DNA are based on the pucker on the sugar ribose. As DNA doesn't have a 2'-OH, it can obtain both conformations.

[image: schematic of Beta vs Alpha from riboses]

RNA does not have this luxury. The steric clash of the 2-OH with the 3'-OH makes the B-form to be very unfavorable thus constraining the RNA to adopt the A-form. Incidentally this steric limitation is also why RNA structures are more stable (see https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/769/389)